# Change the Pandas Dataframe type to String

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I'm working on a chatbot that returns a string message to the user. However, my current code outputs a pandas DataFrame. May I know how to convert this DataFrame to a string output?
Not just for the individual cell value. But the whole DataFrame change to string format.

such that type(df) is string.

```
df = 
     Bearish Neutral Bullish
CLOV   0.041   0.817   0.142
AMD    0.037   0.742   0.222
TTCF   0.063   0.759   0.177

type(df) =
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

Comment: Take a look at [pandas.DataFrame.to_string](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html) or [pandas.DataFrame.to_markdown](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_markdown.html) for more formatted tabular ascii options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to answer your question, depending on how you want the string to be formatted. Probably the simplest are `df.to_csv()` that creates a CSV-like table, and `str(df)` that formats the dataframe more or less the way it looks on your command line.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to output a string representation of the dataframe, you can use `df.to_string()`.

You should get something like:

```
'     Bearish Neutral Bullish\nCLOV   0.041   0.817   0.142\nAMD    0.037   0.742   0.222\nTTCF   0.063   0.759   0.177'
```